# C# - Getting a String from BSTR *

Tags: c#

In a c# application I am working on I am using an API to pull back customer information, and am trying to get a string of the user's email address - the API documentation states that I can call the following on an object to pull back a notefield string (the email address can only be get/set from this function)

```
HRESULT NoteField( [in] BSTR bstrFieldName, [out, retval] BSTR *pNoteField);
```

However when I am calling this in c# I get back an empty string

```
string email = object.NoteField["Email"]
```

How would I be able to get the value?

Comment: How are you including the dll containing NoteField into your C# application?

Comment: It is a reference in the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An unmanaged `BSTR*` and a managed `string` are not the same thing. You need to convert between the two.

[Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringbstr.aspx) and [Marshal.StringToBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtobstr.aspx) should do what you need. Something along the lines of:

```
IntPtr inPtr = Marshal.StringToBSTR("Email");
IntPtr outPtr = object.NoteField[inPtr];
// or you may need to do this
// IntPtr outPtr;
// object.NoteField(inPtr, out outPtr);

string email = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(outPtr);
Marshal.FreeBSTR(inPtr);
Marshal.FreeBSTR(outPtr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer (no pun intended) on where to start, this is returning a compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IntPtr'

Comment: Ah yes indeed, you need to convert the input string to a pointer too! I have updated to include this. Interop is fuuuuun.

Comment: For safety, it is best to use a `try-finally` block around the allocations so you don't get memory leaks if an exception occurs after line 1 and something external catches that error and continues execution.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
string s1 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)outPtr);
```

Comment: This is incorrect (even if it did work for you) this is because BStr strings use `wchar_t` not `char` (two bytes per character) and they *can* contain null characters inside the string instead of only being terminators. See here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/